# Python Subprocess Class

Tags: python, subprocess

I am a learning Python and was trying the subprocess class from the tutorial. The tutorial uses MAC OS hence used **ls -l** . Since i am using Windows OS i used **dir -d** instead.

`import subprocess
subprocess.run(["dir", "-d"])`

**When ran the code in the terminal it prompts**

```
 C:\Users\Farhan Hasant\Desktop\HelloWorld>dir -d
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 8296-8904
 Directory of C:\Users\Farhan Hasant\Desktop\HelloWorld
 File Not Found
```

**Again, when i ran the code using code runner in VS code it shows**

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Farhan Hasant\Desktop\HelloWorld\app.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Farhan Hasant\Desktop\HelloWorld\app.py", line 3, in <module>
subprocess.run(["dir", "-d"])
File "C:\Users\Farhan Hasant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "C:\Users\Farhan Hasant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in init
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\Farhan Hasant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
startupinfo)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.213 seconds
```

**My files** [image]

I am confused if I am doing it right. I would really appreciate your input on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly were you expecting `dir -d` to do?  That's not how you give parameters to Windows-native commands, they use a slash rather than a dash to indicate options.  You're trying to list a nonexistent file named `-d`, of course it's not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir` is not a real command in Windows, it's something builtin in the "shell" so you need to tell `subprocess` to launch a shell **before** attempting to run the command:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["dir", "/d"],shell=True)
```

Also, follow @jasonharper comment about using `/` instead of `-` for most Windows native commands